# PHP Passing a variable to another page then pass it back to the original page

Tags: php

This is a little bit quite confusing to explain. I want to know how to store a string into a variable and pass it to the next page and in that next page pass that variable again to another variable then that variable will pass it back to the original page.


Example:

I have two PHP pages. lets call them **form1.php** and **form2.php**


In form1.php, I will input **Hello** and it will be stored in **var1**.

var1 will be sent to form2.php and it is stored in var2 in form2.php as well.

in form2.php, var2 is passed to var3 and var3 will be sent back to form1.php.

And output **Hello** in form1.php using var3 not var1.

This is where I got stuck. Can't figure out how to do this. Please comment if the question is a little vague, even I cant seem to figure it out myself. Thanks.

Comment: Why so many variables and confusion. Just use `Sessions` for such purpose.

Comment: This looks redundant to me .

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, maybe there are better ways.

Comment: You need to store data in either session or cookies in order to access it in various http requests

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Sessions. With sessions you can pass variables to a different page.

You have to start sessions on both pages.

```
 session_start();
```

After that you can store variables in a session.

For example:

```
$var1 = $_SESSION['name'];
```

Now you can use IT in every page with session_start();

Comment: +1 - I was about to say the same about sessions. Only thing I'd say is the code should be `$var1 = $_SESSION['name'];`

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistakes. I am on my phone wit autocorrect

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are actually using forms then you should be able to just grab the values of the variables in $_GET or $_POST (depending on the method used by the forms). You could just store the values in hidden inputs the user doesn't see and use that to pass things around:

`<input type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo $_GET['var2'];?>" />`

If this isn't what you need you may want to look at [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to maintain state throughout your site.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to pass some data between two distinct forms - you need to consider that these forms are completely independent form each other so you will need to pass data back to the browser or leverage a server side session.

Depending on your use case you could:

Submit data to form1.php - this would then return a form with additional fields ready for submision to form2.php

The trick here - is that data that needs to be passed between forms would be included in the generation of the second form as hidden elements.

```
<input type="hidden" id="var1" value="data from form1" />
```

You can have as many hidden types as you need.

Be aware this approach is not very secure - so you may need consider defences e.g. csrf - or using sessions and tracking the data on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need two forms to send data from the first to the second and from the second back to the first. In this communication, you don't need the third var, how about this?

**form1.php**

```
<form method=POST action="form2.php">
  <input type="text" name="var1" value="<?=@$_POST["var2"];?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

**form2.php**

```
<form method=POST action="form1.php">
  <input type="text" name="var2" value="<?=@$_POST["var1"];?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```